# Excel OFFSET function to work on visible cell only / Formula to generate summary title for repeated cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the data as shown in the image below. This is sorted on column B (Project Priority). I want to create a helper column to show the Priority label based only on the first 'visible' priority name from Column B. The current formula that I am using for Column C works fine for unfiltered data but not when I apply filter. For example, if I exclude Row 2 (Project 01), the summarized label in Column C will become invisible too.

Is there a way to make the values in Column C to adjust to visible cells only? I know this could probably be achieved with the combination of SUBTOTAL(103,ref), OFFSET but I have not been able to figure this out. I want to avoid VBA if at all possible.

Thanks a lot in advance.

[image: sample data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work in C2 and copy down

English

```
=IF(OR(AND(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,B2)=0,SUBTOTAL(103,B2)=1),AND(SUBTOTAL(103,B2)=1,B2<>B1)),B2,"")
```

German

```
=WENN(ODER(UND(ZÄHLENWENN($C$1:C1;B2)=0;TEILERGEBNIS(103;B2)=1);UND(TEILERGEBNIS(103;B2)=1;B2<>B1));B2;"")
```

best regards chris

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am afraid it didn't work as desired, for example, when rows 3 & 4 filtered out, then it shows two labels of CRITICAL.

Comment: This is the base line for what I posted, all you need is to incude all the lines above like I did in my answer.

Comment: But I think your solution will also not work if there are more then 4 CRITICAL rows ?!

Comment: @Rajesh: I edit my answer. I think now it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line to see if the call is visible or hidden and change it's value by that.

`= IF( SUBTOTAL(103,A2)=1, "VISIBLE", "HIDDEN (or blank)" )`

For more information you can look at 
https://superuser.com/questions/885159/excel-function-determine-if-a-cell-is-visible

Comment: Thanks! I know SUBTOTAL can be used for determining if the cell is hidden or visible. The problem is I am unable to achieve the desired outcome as shown in Column C for filtered data.

Comment: Why not? That happends when you try?

Comment: Could you please help in how to generate the labels in Column C? The desired result is that the generated label should appear on the first visible row.
Few examples,- if 'Project 01' is filtered out, the CRITICAL label should appear in C3 because that is the first visible row for 'CRITICAL' group
- if 'Project 01' & 'Project 02' are filtered out, the CRITICAL label should appear in C4 because that is the first visible row for 'CRITICAL' group
- if 'Project 02' & 'Project 03' are filtered out, the CRITICAL label should appear in C2 because that is the first visible row for 'CRITICAL' group

Answer (score 1):

Not the Best solution but it works.

The formula:

`=IF(AND(SUBTOTAL(103,A5)=1,C4<>B5,C3<>B5,C2<>B5),B5,"")`

[image]